# Hey I am coding this and I am having difficulties with it

Tags: java, recursion

I am having difficulties coding this and was wondering if someone can help me code this program. 
If someone can help me get started then that'd be great. Thank you. 
Also I was wondering what sections that I need topics I need to study for this because I am trying to code and having a really difficult time coding this. I know, strange, because I havent had this difficulty since I started CS first.

```
            //Homework: revise this file, see TODO items below.

            //Given a maze of size N, the method findPath(maze) finds an open
            //path from (0,0) to (N-1,N-1), if such a path exists.
            //
            //See main() comments for its command line usage.

            //TODO: the current solution is recursive (dfs() calls itself).  You
            //need to make it non-recursive.  One way is to use an explicit stack
            //instead of the runtime stack.  You do not need to find exactly the
            //same open paths as found by the given code.

            //TODO(EC): modify findPath so it finds a *shortest* open path from
            //(0,0) to (N-1,N-1), when one exists.  You can read about a method
            //for this, "breadth first search", in Section 4.1 of your book.

            //TODO(EC): define the method findWallPath.  Whenever findPath fails to
            //find a path, there should be a "blocking" path of walls.  This path
            //can start at any wall on the top or right sides of the maze, and
            //end at any wall at the bottom or left sides of the maze.  Two walls
            //can be adjacent by a cardinal OR diagonal step.  Again, recursion
            //is not allowed.  Finding a wall path is good, shortest is better.

            //For grading, we ignore the main() method, so do what you like with
            //that.  We only test your findPath and findWallPath methods.

            public class PathFinder
            {
             // Any data fields here should be private and static.  They exist
             // only as a convenient way to share search context between your
             // static methods here.   It should be possible to call your
             // findPath() method more than once, on different mazes, and
             // to get valid results for each maze.

             // The maze we are currently searching.
             private static Maze m;

             // GOAL: for each reachable open position p, parent[p.i][p.j]
             // should be an open position that is closer to the start position
             // S.  These parent links should form a tree, rooted at S.
             private static Position[][] parent;

             public static Deque<Position> findPath(Maze maze)
             {
                 m = maze;                           // save the maze
                 int N = m.size();                   // the maze is N by N
                 parent = new Position[N][N];        // initially all null
                 Position S = new Position(0,0);     // start of search
                 Position T = new Position(N-1,N-1); // goal of search

                 // Compute parent for each position reachable from S.
                 // Since S is the root, we will let S be its own parent.

                 // Compute parent links, by recursive depth-first-search!
                 dfs(S, S);

                 // If T has no parent, it is not reachable, so no path.
                 if (parent[T.i][T.j]==null)
                     return null;
                 // Otherwise, we can reconstruct a path from S to T.
                 LinkedDeque<Position> path = new LinkedDeque<Position>();
                 for (Position u=T; !u.equals(S); u=parent[u.i][u.j])
                     path.addFirst(u);
                 path.addFirst(S);
                 return path;
             }

             // depth-first-search: set parent for each reachable p.
             private static void dfs(Position p, Position from)
             {
                 if (!m.inRange(p) || !m.isOpen(p) || parent[p.i][p.j] != null)
                     return;
                 // System.out.println("found " + p + " via parent " + from);
                 parent[p.i][p.j] = from;
                 // Now recursively try the four neighbors of p.
                 for (int dir=0; dir<4; ++dir)
                     dfs(p.neighbor(dir), p);
             }

             // This method is entirely up to you.
             public static Deque<Position> findWallPath(Maze maze) { return null; }

             // Usage:
             //    java PathFinder MAZEFILE
             // Reads maze, finds path, prints maze with path.
             public static void main(String[] args)
                 throws java.io.IOException
             {
                 Maze m = new Maze(args[0]);
                 System.out.println(m);
                 Deque<Position> path = findPath(m);
                 if (path==null) {
                     System.out.println("No path found");
                     return;
                 }
                 System.out.println("Found path of " +
                                    path.size() +
                                    " positions");
                 System.out.println(path);
                 char[][] map = m.copyArray();
                 // Mark the path with X's
                 for (Position p: path)
                 {
                     assert map[p.i][p.j] == '0';
                     map[p.i][p.j] = 'X';
                 }
                 // Now print the marked map.
                 System.out.println(Maze.toString(map));
             }

             // Java "best practice": this class is all static, so we should
             // never instantiate it.  To enforce that, we make its default
             // constructor private.
             private PathFinder() {}
            }
```

Comment: Do you have a ***specific*** question?

Comment: You've making several mistakes in how you're asking this question that can lead to its being down-voted or closed including not asking a *specific* question, basically *dumping* work for us to do for you (ain't gonna happen), and posting a title that does not summarize your actual problem. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: [How to Ask and Answer Homework Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach to this problem would be to translate the maze (if it isn't yet) into a graph and afterwards implement either in-depth or breadth-first search that searches for the exit of the maze. And btw. you shouldn't write anything about homework in your post.

Comment: Actually I believe the guidance is that you *should* state that it is homework.

Comment: It mattes little whether it's homework or not, as the original question reads more like a work order than an actual question, and it should be improved.

Comment: Better still than stating, `"you shouldn't write anything about homework in your post."` would be to direct him to the [proper way to ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Also [How to avoid doing kids CS homework for them?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281032/how-to-avoid-doing-kids-cs-homework-for-them)